# Post a photo from an album to Facebook wall without losing comments

Tags: facebook, photos

In Facebook I have an existing photo that I uploaded to an album. The photo has people's comments and tags, etc.

Is there any way to post the photo on my wall without re-uploading the via my status?

I don't want to lose all the comments and stuff. I just want to photo to appear as a post on my wall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just click "Share" in the bottom right menu

[image: Bottom right menu to share]

If you are in the overlay display, or bottom left if you're on the picture's page

[image: Overlay display]